# Why are there no char.IsUpperInvariant / char.IsLowerInvariant methods?

Tags: c#, .net, globalization, invariantculture

`Char` implements the methods `ToLowerInvariant` and `ToUpperInvariant` to transform a character to upper/lower case independent of the current culture. However, there are no `IsUpperInvariant` and `IsLowerInvariant` methods. Why?

Comment: As a workaround, you can write one yourself.

Comment: What would they return? True if ToUpperInvariant/ToLowerInvariant would return itself?

Comment: I think the short answer is that it's not needed enough to make it into mscorlib, and `c == Char.ToLowerInvariant(c)` is only few characters more than `Char.IsLowerInvariant(c)`. Also, if it's added for `IsLower`, it will probably have to be added to most of the other `Char.Is` methods

Answer (score 2):

The following methods are the best you can get:

- [Char.IsUpper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Char.IsLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.islower(v=vs.110).aspx)

Once a character is converted to lower/upper format, whether the conversion was culture specific or not, they will properly detect its case.

On the other hand, you cannot say if a given character is the product of a culture specific or an invariant transformation. You can just look at it and observe that its current case is either lower or upper. Given, for example, the character `E` obtained from an upper case transformation... how can you say if it originally was `ë` or `e`? If you don't know it's original form and the current culture the system is using... you simply can't.